# android studio gradle error when compiling

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

My Android studio is giving me errors when I try to compile, it has been working since for sometime now but recently it gives me this error:

```
Could not find any matches for com.android.tools.build:gradle:+ as no versions of com.android.tools.build:gradle are available.
Searched in the following locations:
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/
    file:/Users/macbook/.m2/repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml
    file:/Users/macbook/.m2/repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/
Required by:
    unspecified:unspecified:unspecified
```

Comment: Replace `+` with the required version

Comment: past your build.gradle file

Comment: there already like 10 questions  (with answers) with the same problem for the last 8 hours. Make sure you have searched before asking. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53720321/android-studio-could-not-find-matches-as-no-versions-of-com-android-tools-build

Comment: @Rohit5k2, how do i know the required version

Answer (score 0):

Add `maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools/"  }` to you `android/build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools/"  }
   }
}
```